# How to find the path of any specific file, "just like search", through python

Tags: python, file-search

I'm running a script and as a task I download a file(not from python: Say the user downloads a txt file from browser) and it could be downloaded anywhere by the user. In the next step I want a script to find that file and give me the path for loading the file .. 
I was trying to emulate following osacript from python

```
cmd1 = "find ~ -type f -name \"sometextfile.txt\""
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1.strip().split(" "), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print output
```

but it's saying couldn't find "find: ~"

Is there a way I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` this way:

```py
import glob

file_ = glob.glob("sometextfile*")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through the desired directory and check if you encounter the file:

```
import os

def find_file(root_path, searched_file):
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(root_path):
        if searched_file in filenames:
            return os.path.join(root, searched_file)

output = find_file(os.environ['HOME'], 'sometextfile.txt')  # or whatever base directory
```

Comment: for example if my file(list.html) is in some sub directory of Documents dir.. when I run the previous script with the "list.html" in place of "sometextfile.txt", I get the following result always>     /Users/saurabh.datta/Desktop/list.html which is not my directory

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a `list.html` file on your desktop? Even though you might have one in another directory, this function only returns the path of the first file encountered while walking through your disk. If your are looking for `/Users/saurabh.datta/Example/list.html` then no luck, `Desktop` is before `Example`. Either make sure the filename is unique across directories or change `return` to `yield` so you can get several results (with `list(find_file(..., ...))`).